# How to find my synced mp3 on my iphone

Tags: iphone

I synced my iphone 5 with itunes and one mp3 should be then on my iphone.  I cannot find that one.  There is only lists of ones they are trying to get me to download.  Where can I find the one that I synced with itunes?
And how do I get all the other ones they want me to download off of my phone?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open up Settings on your iPhone
2. Select "iTunes & App Store"
3. Tap the switch beside Music under "SHOW ALL" near the top

You should now only see the music that has been synced to your iPhone. The other music that could be potentially downloaded won't appear.

If you want it to list the rest of your library again, you just need to go back into the Settings and turn that option back on.

[image: Screenshot of option to hide available but not present music]